# JSON decode with flexible type

Tags: go

I need to specify a type for decoding JSON data in a flexible manner, meaning the type needs to be specified at runtime.

Consider this snippet: http://play.golang.org/p/F-Jy4ufMPz

```
s := `{"b":[{"x":9},{"x":4}]}`

var a struct {
  B []interface{}
}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &a)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(a)
```

Which will produce `{[map[x:9] map[x:4]]}`. I want to decode to an array of a specific (struct) type instead of `[]interface{}`, without specifying it at compile time.

Is that somehow possible without creating the array up front? (the number of returned items is unknown)

The only way I can think of right now is to encode the returned maps again later, and decode them to the specified type, which would create unnecessary processing overhead.

Comment: Why not just decode to JSON objects and assign as appropriate?

Comment: The object is pretty large, and I want to avoid code duplication when the object's structure is already defined in a struct.

Comment: When/how will you know which type you should decode them into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If not specifying it at compile time, you still need to specify it somewhere.

If specified before the retrieval of the Json data, you can simply do a switch case, Unmarshalling it to your desired object.

If specified *within* the Json data, you can marshal the "flexible" part into a `json.RawMessage` to process it after you've decided what type of struct is suitable:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var s = `{"type":"structx", "data":{"x":9,"xstring":"This is structX"}}`

type JsonStruct struct {
    Type string
    Data json.RawMessage
}

type StructX struct {
    X       float64
    Xstring string
}

type StructY struct {
    Y bool
}

func main() {
    var a *JsonStruct
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    switch a.Type {
    case "structx":
        // We Unmashal the RawMessage part into a StructX
        var s *StructX
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(a.Data), &s)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(s)
    case "structy":
        // Do the same but for structY
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cm5-0kxtxY)

Comment: The problem with `json.RawMessage` is, that I cannot determine how many rows it contains. I guess I need to create a new slice with `reflect.SliceOf` first, then unpack the `RawMessage` to it?

Comment: I am not sure why you need reflection. If the number of items is important to determine the struct, you van always unmarshal it to a `[]json.RawMessage`. The json.Unmarshal will fill the slice for you.

Comment: Yes, I was a little confused. That's what I ended up using. It was because my real data structure was a little more complex than what I posted (the custom type was embedded in an array anonymous struct fields).